# REGEX To Find File

Tags: regex

I'm trying to come up with a REGEX statement that searches for

```
E:\5Year\Logs\text\date\text.NSDQ2.Trans.log.gz
```

in

```
09/29/2006 09:17:41  Adding file E:\6Year\Logs\text\date\text.NSDQ2.Trans.log.gz
```

so far I have this

```
[A-Z]:\\dYear\Logs\.+
```

to find

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put double backslash to match a single backslash character.

```
\b[A-Z]:\\\dYear\\Logs\\.+
```

or

```
\b[A-Z]:\\\d+Year\\Logs\\.+
```